# php script hungs after consuming a large amount of memory

Tags: php, memory-management

I'm running a php script in browser. The php script hungs after consuming more than 600MB bytes. httpd uses 100% cpu. No error appears in log files. I'm using xampp with php 5.4. To simplify the problem, I tested the following script:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1800M');
$b="";
for($i=0;$i<630000000;$i++)
{
     $b.='a';
}
echo "completed!";
?>
```

The script fails with the error:
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 320077824) (tried to allocate 319815657 bytes) 
My system has about 1.5G memory available.  How could this happen?

Comment: What on earth you are trying to with this code?

Comment: Besides creating a string of 630MB in memory (that requires at least double that as it's being built by concatenation) what's the point? Far better to try and keep memory usage low, because there's a large overhead in allocation of new memory blocks

Comment: To check why php cannot allocate memory from available physical memory

Comment: How does php concatenate strings? If you would do this in C#, the string value would not be extended, instead a new string would be created. So old values hang around (take up memory) until garbage collected.

Comment: @Hans - it uses a temporary string in memory to build the concatenation from the strings (also in memory) that are being concatenated; then assigns that temporary string to the variable, in pretty much the way you have described for C#

Comment: The real question is why has the `ini_set('memory_limit', '1800M');` been ignored; because the error shows that the PHP memory limit is `320,077,824` bytes (320MB), not 1800MB

Comment: @MarkBaker The error only says it allocated `320077824` when it tried to allocate `319815657` so it died (weirdly it allocated more?). It doesn't say how much memory is occupied by other things.

Comment: The error is telling you that it had already allocated `320077824` and tried to allocate an additional `319815657` which pushed it over the limit; so the memory limit is set at somewhere between `320077824` and `320077824+319815657`... that's still a lot less than 1800MB

Comment: What is the response from `ini_set('memory_limit', '1800M');`? Is it a boolean false? or the previous value of that setting?

Comment: @Mark Baker ini_set('memory_limit', '1800M'); is successful. The return value is what is set in php.ini(was 512M, but  the same error occurs even I set it to 1500M in php.ini).

Comment: @MarkBaker ,  Can those temporary strings be  garbage collected and released during the loop? If can not, the memory consumption would be Exponential:1+2+3+......, which will soon eat up all the memory.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, they're cleared for garbage collection at the conclusion of the concatenation itself

Answer (score 0):

> My system has about 1.5G memory available.

Not all of that is available to PHP of course.

You need to increase the [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) in your PHP configuration:

> **memory_limit** integer
>   This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no memory limit, set this directive to -1.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing memory_limit=1500M in php.ini cannot solve this problem.

Comment: Interestingly, httpd still uses 100% CPU even I close the brower. I have to stop apache to make it normal. Since there is no error message/log, how to debug this problem?

Comment: Normally script are aborted if the browser closes the connection. Check the `ignore_user_abort` setting in your configuration.